# Optimization of revenue (with multiple products and constraints)

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, model

Have a data science problem, but I am not sure how I can approach the problem.

**Problem:**
I want to optimize my revenue, with my data. Only constraint: stock should be >0 (otherwise we will not sell anything of course).

**What is a right approach for this task?** I built a predictive regression tree, but that didn't showed what I want to have (only high level insights).

**What do I want to have?** Some kind of optimization model(?) which shows me: You will have the highest revenue, if you have Price X for product A, Price X for product B and Price X for product C.

hints are really appriciated. I work in R(studio), so an example in R would be really amazing. Thanks a lot in advance for helping me out!

**Data is like this:**

```
Revenue    Units_sold    Product   Price   Country   stock  
800         74            A         15       USA       0
1000        60            A         10       USA       1
500         76            B         18       GB        2
300         45            B          9       GB        900
800         67            A         11       NL        500
990         99            C         17       NL        0
```